# OpenGL ReadPixels Screenshot Is Not Showing What I See

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm trying to take a screen shot of the OpenGL context as follows:

```
const int pix = 3 * windowWidth * windowHeight;
  GLfloat *pixels = new GLfloat[pix];

  glReadPixels(0, 0, windowWidth, windowHeight, GL_RGB, GL_FLOAT, pixels);
  pngwriter PNG(windowWidth, windowHeight, 0.0, "screenshot.png");
  size_t x = 1;
  size_t y = 1;
  double R, G, B;
  for (size_t i = 0; i < pix; i++) {
    switch (i % 3) {
      case 2:B = (double) pixels[i];
        break;
      case 1:G = (double) pixels[i];
        break;
      case 0:R = (double) pixels[i];
        PNG.plot(x, y, R, G, B);
        if (x == windowWidth) {
          x = 1;
          y++;
        } else { x++; }
        break;
    }
  }
  PNG.close();

  delete[] pixels;
```

This is what I see:

[image: Desktop Screenshot]

This is what I get:

[image: This is what I get]

None of my transformations come out in the screenshot?

Or am I going about this the complete wrong way?

Comment: Have you tried reading unsigned bytes instead of floats?

Comment: Aside: I am curious as to why `x` and `y` start at (and `x` resets to) 1 and not 0. `glReadPixels(0, 0, windowWidth, windowHeight, ...)` is obviously 0-based.

Comment: You perform the plot in the `i%3==0` (`R`) case, but this is the first case you get to, `G` and `B` for this pixel have not been read yet.

Comment: @Weather Vane I agree that it's strange, but it looks like PngWriter actually uses 1-based coordinates for its `plot` function: http://pngwriter.sourceforge.net/ "**The pixels are numbered starting from (1, 1) and go to (width, height)**"

Comment: I'm guessing `windowWidth` and `windowHeight` are not correct, how do you determine them?

Comment: The window itself is 1280 x 720 increasing the number does nothing

Comment: Hmm, which buffer are you reading from? I'm not sure that the contents of  the back buffer are guaranteed to be preserved after a swap. Try glReadBuffer(GL_FRONT)?

Comment: Reading the front buffer didn't change anything unfortunately.

Comment: Following up on Christopher Oicle, have you actually printed out the values of window width and height to make sure they're correct?